# github - code pulled from master,push changes to new branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I am working on a project where I created a local repo from "master" github branch.However a new branch was forked from the master a while later.Now I want to push my changes to the new branch.I would like to avoid merging for now and just push my current local code-base to the new branch.Any suggestions on the right approach?

Comment: If you're the only one that pushes to that repo, you can force the push.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git checkout -b newBranchName` this will create a new branch with all of your commits and files. You can the push this changes without effecting the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Create local branch `git checkout -b myLocalBranch`.
Pushing this branch to repo `git push origin myLocalBranch`.